# how to join 3 tables in single query

Tags: sql

i have this query

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,
count(dbo.IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId) as Orders,
OverallTotal = (select sum(in_total) from IN_Invoices where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=2 and datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014)
from IN_Invoices
inner join CLOI_ClientOrderItems on IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=2 and datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014
group by cl_id
```

result

```
cl_id         orders overalltotoal 
100000pro       5       39949
100001pro       64      39949
```

the result showing same for both orders i need to show the overall total for particular cl_id orders..

Comment: It's because the calculation for OverAllTotal does not have condition on cl_id, but instead it seems to grab the total for all invoices.

Comment: howcan do tatfor particular cl_id order for overalltotal

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,f.MasterOrderId as orders ,f.in_total as total
   from(select sum(in_total),count(MasterOrderId) from IN_Invoices where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=2 and datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014 group by cl_id)as f,IN_Invoices
   inner join CLOI_ClientOrderItems on IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=2 and datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014
group by cl_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a schema to test this on, it's really hard to see whether or not something works, but seeing you already have the WHERE clause you added in the calculation for OverallTotal, this might do the trick for you:

```
select 
 dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems.cl_id,
 count(dbo.IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId) as Orders,
 sum(in_total) AS OverallTotal
from IN_Invoices
 inner join CLOI_ClientOrderItems on   
 IN_Invoices.MasterOrderId=CLOI_ClientOrderItems.MasterOrderId
where datepart(mm,in_date_issued)=2 and datepart(yyyy,in_date_issued)=2014
group by cl_id
```

If not, please provide a sqlfiddle of your schema and some data.

Comment: how can i provide u fields

Comment: www.sqlfiddle.com - add your database schema and some data, and then let us know the expected outcome.